# “As if” is followed by a gerund?

Tags: parts-of-speech, passive-voice, gerund-phrases

Here is the first definition of *[prolepsis](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prolepsis)* by Merriam-Webster:

- the representation or assumption of a future act or development **as if presently existing or accomplished***

My questions:
1. Is *existing* there a gerund?
2. Is *accomplished* there in the passive form?
3. So  *as if* does not have to be followed by a clause?

Comment: No - it's just one continuous and one past participle both used adjectivally (to modify the noun phrase "a future act or development"). But what difference does it make to *you* whether any given ***-ing*** form is a "verb" or a "noun" (gerund)?

Comment: @FumbleFingers I just wanna know deeper about the grammatical aspect of the phrase. I love English and really wanna know everything about the usage, especially the grammatical usage, but the more I learn, the stranger it is.

Comment: Then you should "parse" the cited text as reduced from "subjunctive" *...as if **it were** presently existing or accomplished*. Where ***it*** explicitly refers back to the relevant preceding noun phrase as pointed out above, ***adjectivally modified*** by what follows. In principle you could have an actual noun (rather than an adjective) after ***as if*** in such constructions, but idiomatically that more strongly calls for the explicit pronoun reference: *The boy spoke to his mother as if [**he were**] an adult* seems pretty "ugly" to me without the highlighted explicit reference.

Comment: @FumbleFingers got it. Thanks fumble. By the way, please give me some more free brief explanation. *Existing* there is in a present participle form, right? To my knowledge, *exist* in such a context should always be in the present when it bears this sense. Is that right? If it is, then how come that *exist* is in that form? Then, in the phrase *as if it were presently existing or accomplished*, shouldn't there be another *were* before *accomplished*?

Comment: If you want to learn about English, I suggest you stop saying "wanna" and use the correct firm "want to". And why analyse dictionary definitions, which often contain ellipsis and other shortenings? Have you got a decent modern grammar text book?

Comment: @BillJ sorry for that. I did that out of force of habit.

Comment: @tchrist sorry, but are you high on weed right now? :D